# Weird zoom jump beetween 1904px and 1903px

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on vue project with vuetify library,
I found weird zoom jump between 1904px and 1903px.
19xx px doesn't match any size in styles (I mean sizes like md, lg)

I want to know why it happened
Is it a settings with vuetify or vue? or is it a browser setting?

[1904 px zoom 75](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFPQ8.png)

[1903 px zoom 81](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCsXW.png)

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers? It does not sound related to Vue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is entirely unrelated to your project and is simply based on your browser window size as the zoom is strictly used to display different aspect ratios within your browser.